# How to use notifications.get

Tags: c#, facebook, notifications

I'm making an application in C# which plays a sound when I receive a notification on Facebook.

I tried to find something, but that's all: [documentation for *notifications.get*](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/notifications.get/)

But I can't understand how use it. Is this function useful or do I need to take another road?

I need to know not only the notifications but also the messages notifications and friends request notifications. I don't need the number but just to know if there is something new.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to do Facebook authentication and get an access token. Then you can poll for notifications and messages. To do that you have to use [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API), the rest is deprecated.

See:

- *[Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)*
- *[Notification](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/notification/)*
- *[Message](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/)*